# How to pass values to input field's value with spaces

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

```
<form action="handleAppointment/" method="post" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="inputfield">
            <label for="doctor" class="label">Doctor</label>
            <input type="text" name="doctor" id="doctor" class="input" value={{ doctorName.name }} >
        </div>
```

this is my form i want full value from database.but here {{doctorName.name}} is showing value which is before space.

```
def bookAppointment(request , id ):
  doctor = Doctor.objects.filter(id = id ).first()
  print(doctor.name)

  context = {'doctorName': doctor}
  return render(request , 'patient/appointmentForm.html' , context)
```

after running this code it shows ' Tapan Shah ' as output in terminal.
which is full name but it shows ' Tapan ' before space value in frontend.

Comment: Use Trim function in your javascript or in database you can use LTRIM, RTRIM but it is not good idea to trim at db level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the `.py` file...

In the `bookAppointment` function you can pass an extra variable to the template. For example:

```
def bookAppointment(request, id ):
  doctor = Doctor.objects.filter(id=id).first()
  first_name = doctor.name.split()[0]  # see here...

  context = {'doctorName': doctor, 'first_name': first_name}
  return render(request, 'patient/appointmentForm.html', context)
```

Please note that `doctor.name.split()` will then make a list from the doctor's name for example ['firstname', 'lastname']. By using `doctor.name.split()[0]` will call for the doctor's firstname and assign it to the variable first_name.

Within the .html file...

```
<div class="inputfield">
    <label for="doctor" class="label">Doctor</label>
    <input type="text" name="doctorName.name" id="doctorName.id" class="input" value={{ first_name }} >
</div>
```

So instead of having `value={{ doctorName.name }}` you would just use `value={{ first_name }}` but do ensure you have the `id="doctorName.id"` that you can refer this information elsewhere if needed.

Comment: If this solution got your problem solved maybe you can accept it as your answer. :-)